# How to correct result from subpatterns in regular expression of preg_match_all?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have this code:

```
$query = 'CREATE table "msg" ( "myid" INT(10) UNSIGNED , "user" INT(10) UNSIGNED , "new_mes" SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED , "total_mes" MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED , "lastdate" DATETIME , PRIMARY KEY ("ids"), KEY ("lastdate") )';
```

I am trying to get Primary Key and Key using this subpaterns:

```
preg_match_all('/(?:\WPRIMARY\W*KEY\W?\()(?P<PRIMARY_KEY>[^)]+)|'.
        '(?:\W*KEY\W?\()(?P<KEY>[^)]+)/i',$query,$results);
        $primary_key = isset($results['PRIMARY_KEY'][0]) ? $results['PRIMARY_KEY'][0] : '';
        $key = isset($results['KEY'][0]) ? $results['KEY'][0] : '';
    print_r($results);
```

I get this output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  PRIMARY KEY ("ids"
            [1] => ),KEY ("lastdate"
        )

    [PRIMARY_KEY] => Array
        (
            [0] => "ids"
            [1] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => "ids"
            [1] => 
        )

    [KEY] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => "lastdate"
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => "lastdate"
        )
)
```

I looked for the words enclosed in double quotes. The result is almost find but I would prefer to get the two words "ids" and "lastdate" in first index [0]. Can you explain why it happens that the first word is placed in the first index, whilst the second one is placed in the second index? And why there are empty strings in second and on first index.

Is there way how to get both words on index 0? Just to simplify the code.

Comment: Do you need the named capture groups by all means? You could just use [`(?|\WPRIMARY\W*KEY\W?\(([^)]+)|\W*KEY\W?\(([^)]+))`](https://regex101.com/r/kG6nE6/1). See [this demo](http://ideone.com/sBLOYZ).

Comment: I know I don't need them. I created them just to make things clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check how your regex works with [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/aU3lM7/1), in the top right sidebar.

An alternate way to do the job ([see online demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4032d7d1b4ef792dbe7b9326a45a422d951541cc)):

```php
<?php
// I added a primary key `myid` to demonstrate a capture with several keywords
$query = 'CREATE table "msg" ( "myid" INT(10) UNSIGNED , "user" INT(10) UNSIGNED , "new_mes" SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED , "total_mes" MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED , "lastdate" DATETIME , PRIMARY KEY ("ids", "myid"), KEY ("lastdate") )'; 

// 1. Note the \b anchor to ensure that the capture begins at the start of a word
// 2. PREG_SET_ORDER to keep structure simplier
preg_match_all('#\b((?:PRIMARY\s*?)?KEY) \(([^\)]*)\)#i', $query, $results, PREG_SET_ORDER);

$primary_keys = [];
$keys = [];

foreach ($results as $result) {
    $values = explode(',', $result[2]); // get separate words
    array_walk($values, function (&$v) { $v = trim($v, ' "'); }); // remove quotes and spaces
    if (0 === stripos($result[1], 'PRIMARY')) {
        $primary_keys = array_merge($primary_keys, $values);
    }
    else {
        $keys = array_merge($keys, $values);
    }
}

echo "Found primary keys:\n";
print_r($primary_keys);
echo "Found keys:\n";
print_r($keys);

echo "\n\$results:\n";
print_r($results);
```

**Result:**

```
Found primary keys:
Array
(
    [0] => ids
    [1] => myid
)
Found keys:
Array
(
    [0] => lastdate
)

$results:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => PRIMARY KEY ("ids", "myid")
            [1] => PRIMARY KEY
            [2] => "ids", "myid"
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => KEY ("lastdate")
            [1] => KEY
            [2] => "lastdate"
        )

)
```

You can see on Regex101 that [this new version](https://regex101.com/r/aU3lM7/2) is more efficient that [the old one](https://regex101.com/r/aU3lM7/1) with 377 steps vs 904 steps to capture the results.

Comment: Thanks. This one is better. What does the \b in your pattern?

Comment: @JohnBoe It indicates that I search to find the beginning of the words `PRIMARY` or `KEY`. The regex engine can optimize research by simply testing the beginning of the words of the text to parse.
Also, I ensures that another words which contain `PRIMARY` or `KEY` are not catched, like `FOREIGN KEY`.